# How can i use same serializer in Create and List Views

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a PostSerializer and this serializer have an user field. Also i have a UserSerializer. So i want to use UserSerializer in the PostSerializer like this

```py
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(many=False)
    class Meta:
         fields = ('user', 'title')
```

But i got the error when i try to use in the CreateView because i dont send UserSerializer data, i send user_id.

I have to use same Serializer in Create and List view. Because i use to ListCreateAPIView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have to deal with this kind of serialization I do it like this:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_data = UserSerializer(
        read_only=True,
        source='user',
    )

    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'user',
            'user_data',
            'title',
        )
```

You will get `user_data` when you are reading, and you will need only user's id as `user` when writing.